# htaccess rewrite rule doesn't work

Tags: php, linux, apache, unix, .htaccess

in my .htaccess file i do have these lines:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule
^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9])/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.(html)$ /first_gate/index.php?show=true&_=$1&__=$2 [QSA]
```

So calling:

```
http://www.domain.com/a-b-c-d/123/an-thing-here.html
```

in the background it's intended to be:

```
http://www.domain.com/first_gate/index.php?show=true&cat=a-b-c-d&sub_cat=123
```

> The (an-thing-here) part wouldn't be
>   used for retreiving data but just to
>   improve SEO.

I got: 404 Not found.

Any help would be soooo much appreciated.
Thank you,

Comment: Try adding [R] to the parameters so you can see where it redirects to.

Comment: Seems like a question for serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second pattern group is only matching a single digit, try this instead:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule
^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.(html)$ /first_gate/index.php?show=true&_=$1&__=$2 [QSA]
```

I just added a `+` after the pattern `[0-9]`.

Comment: Waw!
It's clear that i'm new on this!
Works fine, thank you so much,